# Continuity of a Function in Terms of Closure and Interior

Tags: general-topology

I've managed to show that the following are equivalent (where $f^*$ and $f_*$ are the preimage and image of f respectively):

$\bullet$ $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous

$\bullet$ $f^*(S^{\circ}) \subseteq f^*(S)^{\circ}$

$\bullet$ $\overline{f^*(S)} \subseteq f^*(\overline{S})$

$\bullet$ $f_*(\overline{S}) \subseteq \overline{f_*(S)}$

Is the following also equivalent: $f_*(S)^\circ \subseteq f_*(S^\circ)$ (or something similar)? I've not managed to get very far, although my proof of condition 3 hinged on the fact that preimages, complements, interiors and closures all behave well together, whereas this is not case for the image of a function, so I feel this may not be true.

Comment: I'm not sure what $S$ is, but what if $f(S)$ is just a finite set of points? Then the condition $f(S)^{\circ} \subset f(S^{\circ})$ is vacuous. For example, look at $\mathbf{R} \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ given by $x \mapsto x/|x|$ if $x \neq 0$ and $0 \mapsto 1$. Then the image is just two points, so the interior of the image is the empty set.

Comment: S is a subset of X or Y. Isn't this a non-issue though, since it doesn't contradict anything?

Answer (score 3):

tkr provided an example that shows that int$(f(S))\subseteq f($int$(S)$ does not imply continuity. To see that continuity does not imply the property consider $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R_{\ge0}$,
$f(x)=\begin{cases}
0, \text{ if }x\le0\\
x, \text{ if }x\ge0
\end{cases}$
Let $S=[0,1]$. Then int$(f(S))=[0,1)$, but $f($int$(S))=(0,1)$

On the other hand, this map $f$ considered as a map $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ does not satisfy $f($int$(S))\subseteq$ int$(f(S))$ (the reverse inclusion), since for $S=[-1,1]$ the former is $[0,1)$ while the later is $(0,1)$.

To see that this inclusion does not imply continuity, consider the map $g:\Bbb R\to \{0,1\}$
$g(x)=\begin{cases}
0 \text{, if }x<0\\
1 \text{, if }x\ge0
\end{cases}$

But you can show that the later inclusion is equivalent to openness of $f$. The former inclusion is rather useless.

Comment: Thanks, that clears things up. I wasn't thinking straight earlier, and without knowing whether it was true or not, didn't bother looking too hard for a counterexample.

Comment: @SimonC: Don't forget to upvote if you find my answer useful ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The continuous image of a non-empty set with empty interior may have non-empty interior, so we may have $(f_*(S))^o\not=\phi$ and $f_*(S^o)=\phi$. For example, if f is the Devil's Staircase function, which maps [0,1] onto itself continuously,and S is the Cantor set,then f(S)=[0,1] and int(S)=$\phi$.