# Prove that $f$ is continuous on $X$ iff $int(f(A)) \subset f(intA)$.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X,Y$ be two topological spaces and $f:X \rightarrow Y$. Prove that $f$ is continuous on $X$ iff $int(f(A)) \subset f(intA)$.

My attempt: ($\Rightarrow$) Assume that $y \in int(f(A))$. I tried to prove $y \in f(int(A))$.
We have $V$ is an open set : $y \in V \subset f(A)$. So there is an $x \in A$: $y=f(x)$. Because of the continuity of $f$, there is an open set $U$ containing $x$ and $f(U) \subset V$. It leads to $f(U) \subset f(A)$, but I'm not sure $x \in U \subset A$.

I wonder if we have $f$ is injective then can I say $f(U) \subset f(A)$ then $U \subset A$ ?

($\Leftarrow$) I have already known the solution.

Is there any solution for this ? Thank you.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387845/continuity-of-a-function-in-terms-of-closure-and-interior

Comment: I don't think that is a duplicate.